# How to blacklist the galcore kernel module from yocto rootfs

Tags: yocto, kernel-module, blacklist, imx6

A kernel module name galcore.ko is making my imx6slevk board hang while booting.
The path to this file is:
/lib/modules/4.9.88-imx_4.9.88_2.0.0_ga+g5e23f9d61147/extra/galcore.ko
on manually deleting this .ko file and flashng rootfs the board boots fine. 
I'd like to modify the yyocto source to prevent this .ko file from auto loading.

I've tried adding

```
PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "imx-gpu-viv"
```

and also

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "imx-gpu-viv"
```

into my fsl-image-validation-qt5.bb file but neither of them had any effect.

This is the bb file for autoloading of galcore

```
inherit module
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx-src.inc
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "CONFIG_MXC_GPU_VIV=m"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD = ""
```

If I give "n" in the above OEMAKE path I get an error that says

```
ERROR: kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv-6.2.4.p1.2-r0 do_package: QA Issue: kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
/lib
/lib/modules
/lib/modules/4.9.88-imx_4.9.88_2.0.0_ga+g5e23f9d61147
/lib/modules/4.9.88-imx_4.9.88_2.0.0_ga+g5e23f9d61147/extra
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install
```

How can I blacklist this kernel module or prevent it from autoloading?

Comment: You try to remove the package "imx-gpu-viv" from your IMAGE_INSTALL but at least the packaging error mentions "kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv". Maybe doublecheck which package actually contains your module?

Comment: You can add something like `KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF += "galcore"   module_conf_galcore = "blacklist galcore"`, see [module_conf](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-module_conf) [KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF)

Comment: @Nayfe should I add these in local.conf or the .bb file of rootfs?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen if I remove the entire package I won't be able to run gpu applications, it's just the galcore.ko that I need removed

Comment: @Producer: Ok, I'll take your word for it. You don't link to the layer so I couldn't have a look at the whole thing -- the recipe you included just seemed to be for a single module...

Comment: In manual `You can use this variable anywhere that it can be recognized by the kernel recipe or out-of-tree kernel module recipe (e.g. a machine configuration file, a distribution configuration file, an append file for the recipe, or the recipe itself).`

Comment: @Nayfe Thank you, that worked for me. Can you please post a link of the "manual" from where you cited that paragraph also... why not add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To blacklist galcore kernel module, you should set following bitbake variables whereas in:

- `local.conf`
- `virtual/kernel` recipe bbappend
- recipe providing galcore module bbappend
- machine configuration
- distro configuration

```
KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF += "galcore"
module_conf_galcore = "blacklist galcore"
```

It will create a `/etc/modprobe.d/galcore.conf` file with `module_conf` content.

---

See mega manual:

- [Kernel Module Autoloading](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-1.7-kernel-module-autoloading)
- [module_conf](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-module_conf)
- [KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF)